# Read a text file into python by splitting the file into list items according to a set of characters

Tags: python, list, readfile, splice, dna-sequence

I have a plain text file with the following contents:

```
@M00964: XXXXX
YYY
+
ZZZZ 
@M00964: XXXXX
YYY
+
ZZZZ
@M00964: XXXXX
YYY
+
ZZZZ
```

and I would like to read this into a list split into items according to the ID code `@M00964`, i.e. :

```
['@M00964: XXXXX
YYY
+
ZZZZ' 
'@M00964: XXXXX
YYY
+
ZZZZ'
'@M00964: XXXXX
YYY
+
ZZZZ']
```

I have tried using

```
in_file = open(fileName,"r")
sequences = in_file.read().split('@M00964')[1:]
in_file.close()
```

but this removes the ID sequence `@M00964`. Is there any way to keep this ID sequence in?

As an additional question is there any way of maintaining white space in a list (rather than have /n symbols).

My overall aim is to read in this set of items, take the first 2, for example, and write them back to a text file maintaining all of the original formatting.

Comment: `.read()` reads 1 line. Try with `.readlines()` which reads all the lines, and then split on `'\n'`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "maintaining white space in a list (rather than have \n symbols)"? The `\n` is just shorthand for "the newline character", which is white space.

Comment: What does an item look like? You example list above has 1 item only.

Comment: Looks like FASTQ, where a record is _always_ 4 lines. If you want the first 2 records, just print the first `2*4` lines.

Comment: @fredtantini Err, I think you need to check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). Read takes a size argument and, given none, reads _the entire file_.

Comment: Hi, sorry by maintaining whitespace I mean when I have taken the top 2 items and print it back to a text file it has whitespace rather than the actual newline character "/n". As an example currently when I print it off again I get @M00964: XXXXX/nYYY/n+ZZZZ/n@M00964 and so on. Does that make sense?

Comment: It is a FASTQ file, the one I have contains 155,000 sequences and I want the user to input a percentage (10% for example) and a new file to be made with 10% of the reads, i.e. the first 15,500

Comment: @fredtantini rly, read docs. It reads all lines (whole file) if you don't give argument, as it have been pointed out already.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist my bad. I was thinking of `readline` indeed.

Comment: @fredtantini Just correcting the record. If you had every single method in every single language memorized, I would be worried about you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to your example, can't you just do something as follows:

```
in_file = open(fileName, 'r')
file = in_file.readlines()

new_list = [''.join(file[i*4:(i+1)*4]) for i in range(int(len(file)/4))]
list_no_n = [item.replace('\n','') for item in new_list]

print new_list
print list_no_n
```

[EXPANDED FORM]

```
new_list = []
for i in range(int(len(file)/4)): #Iterates through 1/4 of the length of the file lines.
                                  #This is because we will be dealing in groups of 4 lines
    new_list.append(''.join(file[i*4:(i+1)*4])) #Joins four lines together into a string and adds it to the new_list
```

[Writing to new file]

```
write_list = ''.join(new_list).split('\n')
output_file = open(filename, 'w')
output_file.writelines(write_list)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I have only learnt python for the last month or so, could you explain what this code actually does? Thankyou

Comment: @user3460300, The code groups every four lines together and joins them into a string. Then it takes the groups of four lines and combines them into a list. I will update my answer to show an expanded form of what I am doing.

Comment: @user3460300, Note: I have also created another variable called `list_no_n`. This is the same as `new_list` but does not contain any `\n` characters and therefore can be used for data processing within the script. If you want to write the string to another file, you can use the original `new_list` string with its retained `\n` characters and it will keep its formatting. Of course, you can choose to write maybe only the first two sets of data since it is a list.

Comment: so when I write the first two back to a text file how would I do that in a way that would maintain the formatting in the text file rather than having it all one on line with /n characters? Also, thankyou I have managed to get the first bit to work perfectly!!

Comment: @user3460300, You would split the list back based on the \n strings using split('\n') and then you would write it line by line to your new file

Comment: sorry I know this is a really basic question now but how do I do that. I have a list called new_list where each item is the sequence plus the ID as I needed. I have used raw input and some quick calculations to get the first 10% of items into a subset list. I then what to write this item to a new file line by line. I have then done the following: fileName = raw_input("What do you want to call the new filtered file? ") How do I then write the entire subset list line by line?

Comment: @paulbarr, there I updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, finally finished my script! Would upvote you but only joined stackoverflow today

Comment: @paulbarr, no problem. And welcome to stackoverflow. Hope you have a nice time

Answer (score 3):

If your file is large and you don't want hold the whole thing in memory you can just iterate over individual records using this helper function:

```
def chunk_records(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        record = []
        for line in f:
            # could use regex for more complicated matching
            if line.startswith('@M00964') and record:
                yield ''.join(record)
                record = []
            else:
                record.append(line)
        if record:
            yield ''.join(record)
```

Use it like

```
for record in chunk_records('/your/filename.txt'):
    ...
```

Or if you want the whole thing in memory:

```
records = list(chunk_records('/your/filename.txt'))
```

Comment: The newlines in the file are important, so OP should join them with `'\n'` instead of `''`

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, thankyou I will have a look at using this now.

Comment: @rmartinjak do you mean replace '' in the above code with '/n'?

Comment: @martinjak:  The newlines are never stripped so they need not be added back in.  When iterating over lines in a file python leaves the line ending in.

Comment: Oh indeed, I totally forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

Just split on the @ sign instead:

```
with open(fileName,"r") as in_file:
    sequences = in_file.read().replace("@","###@").split('###')
```

Comment: Hi, This still removes the @ symbol, ideally I want to keep the entire ID of @M00946

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski's is more RAM efficient if the file is large. I went for the simplest solution.